# How to create unique_ptr for pair which elements(vector and int) are also unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have searched. but can't find a clear answer. So I created a new question. The codes are as below:

```
using namespace std;

using pairfortsp = pair<unique_ptr<vector<int>>, unique_ptr<int>>;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unique_ptr<vector<int>> tmpptr1(new vector<int>{1});
    unique_ptr<int> tmpptr2(new int(1));
    unique_ptr<pairfortsp> tmpptr3(new pairfortsp<tmpptr1,tmpptr2>);
}
```

When i compiled it, I got following two errors:

```
stackover.cpp:25:50: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('pairfortsp *' (aka
      'pair<unique_ptr<vector<int> >, unique_ptr<int> > *') and 'unique_ptr<vector<int> >')
    unique_ptr<pairfortsp> tmpptr3(new pairfortsp<tmpptr1,tmpptr2>);
..................
stackover.cpp:25:67: error: expected expression
    unique_ptr<pairfortsp> tmpptr3(new pairfortsp<tmpptr1,tmpptr2>);
```

So what is the correct steps to create unique_ptr for the pair like the one I declared?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a careful look at `new pairfortsp<tmpptr1,tmpptr2>`. What does that mean? What did you _intend_ that to mean?

Comment: It means that I want to allocate a space in heap for the pair pairfortsp. I don't know the correct method to allocate heap space for the pair pairfortsp.

Comment: I meant _syntactically_.

Comment: @johnweekthird is `pairfortsp` a template?

Comment: @eerorika, it is std::pair with two unique_ptr elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass constructor arguments to `std::pair` as template parameters. That is, you were using `< >` is instead of `( )`.

Also, since `unique_ptr` cannot be copied, you must `std::move` them to pass them to the constructor.

The following code compiles with `g++ -std=c++17 Move.cc`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

using pairfortsp = pair<unique_ptr<vector<int>>, unique_ptr<int>>;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unique_ptr<vector<int>> tmpptr1(new vector<int>{1});
    unique_ptr<int> tmpptr2(new int(1));
    unique_ptr<pairfortsp> tmpptr3(new pairfortsp(std::move(tmpptr1),std::move(tmpptr2)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, merlin2011. Your answer fixed my problem. So I made two mistakes. First, as you said, I must std::move unique_ptr. second, I used <> tokens to contain the two pair elements. I used () tokens intead. Then no errors now.

Comment: It is better practice to create them using `std::make_unique`

Comment: @Slava, Are you suggesting doing assignment to the return value of `std::make_unique`? Please put your precise code suggestion into the comment.

Comment: I mean `unique_ptr<vector<int>> tmpptr1 = std::make_unique<vector<int>>( 1 );` or even better `auto tmpptr1 = std::make_unique<vector<int>>( 1 );` and so on

Comment: @Slava, I agree with you in principle, but I feel that this much unrelated code modification will occlude the main point of the question. Please feel free to add an additional answer that handles these points.

Comment: I did not say your answer is incorrect or you have to change it, I made a comment that in real code it is better to use this. No worry.